# Finding linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am in trouble at this problem:
Given:

$$u_1 = (1,−1), u_2 = (2,−1), u_3 = (−3, 2)$$
$$v_1 = (1, 0), v_2 = (0, 1), v_3 = (1, 1)$$

is there a linear transformation $T : \mathbb{R}^2 → \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(u_1) = v_1,
T(u_2) = v_2$, and $T(u_3) = v_3$ ? Justify your answer.
Could someone please help me at this?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

If  $c_1 u_1 + c_2 u_2 = u_3$, then $T(c_1u_1 + c_2 u_2) = T(u_3)$.

Edit: (After OP solved the problem)

We have $-u_1-u_2 = u_3$

Hence if that transformation were to exists, then by applying the transformation $T$ on both sides,

$$-v_1 - v_2 = v_3$$

of which we can verify to be not true.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not quite understand the hint. I can figure out c1 and c2 but I dont know how it helps the problem

Comment: Suppose the lienar transformation described in the question exists, can you evaluate $T(c_1u_1+c_2u_2)$?

Comment: Yes, T(c1u1 + c2u2) = c1T(u1) + c2T(u2) = c1v1 + c2v2 as assumption. I figured out c1 = c2 = -1, so if I plug these into the equation, I will get T(u3) = (-1,-1) while v3=(1,1)

Comment: yup, so can we conclude anything about the existence of such linear transformation?

Comment: So that means that linear transformation does not exist right? Thanks anyway

Comment: congratulations, you have solved the problem